Windows 11 - how to quickly start something from desktop without minimizing opened windows?
I just noticed that I am loosing too much every time I want to simply start something from desktop.
Given.
I have lots of applications, documents, etc. as shortcuts on my desktop, they are positioned and organized there nicely, I know where is what located and it's cool to double click to start things.
Then I usually in the middle of work and have complicated layout of opened windows (sometimes I am snapping them to sides, etc.), usually IDE or two, then my software running with debugger, logger and so on. On another monitor almost always is webbrowser and sometimes few more things opened. Complex. Layout. Ok?
What I want.
I want simply open another document or start some app from my desktop, like if it's started by itself on top of what I am doing currently.
Problem.
I can't access desktop and I need to minimize some (or all) opened window until I reach desktop, specifically the part I know where shortcut is, then double-click it, then restoring my layout back (pain)...
Ideally, while in some state (A) I want to see my desktop with one click (B), then double-click something on it and then return to the state (A) with new thing opened on top of everything. Even more better would be if (A) occurs by itself after double-clicking, without need to click something again.
Try clicking "show desktop" button (on the right side of taskbar) twice (or press WIN+D). That's what I want, but if after the first click/press I double click something on desktop, then layout is permanently lost and can't be restored with one more click/press.
Ideas?

Use multiple desktops?

I am not a kin of having multiple desktops: switching is pain, managing (creating/deleting) is pain, windows multi-destkop UI is somewhat laking... Also, accidentally starting app in wrong desktop? Need to access it from another? No no no...

Short of third party tools (which is off topic here) you're not going to be able to maintain the layout on your desktop without actually seeing your desktop.  You could put a shortcut to your desktop folder somewhere like the taskbar for quick access without having to minimize things, but you will obviously lose the layout you've created on the desktop.

I thought about desktop forlder shortcut on taskbur, but explorer window doesn't show all items from my desktop, nor I can find things in explored folder as easy as on desktop.

@JoepvanSteen That's a fair point and great distinction, thanks :)

Solution 1:
Minimize, launch, restore. This isn't minimizing one at a time - it minimizes everything on the desktop

Type Windows+M to minimize everything on the desktop
Launch your application
Type Windows+shift+M to restore everything on the desktop

Solution 2: Multiple desktops (as suggested by @squillman)

Create a new desktop or use one that you are not currently using
Launch your application
To return to your original application, switch desktops
To return to the new application, either switch desktops or move the application to the current desktop

Solution 3: Pin application to Start Menu
If the application is pinned to the Start Menu, there is no need to do anything with the desktops
Solution 4: Pin application to the task bar
Like Solution 3: no need to mess with the desktops

Didn't know about WIN+SHIFT+M, cool, though it doesn't make the opened thing on top and shortcut is hard to press with one hand (other hand will be double-clicking, I wish I have 3). Best of what I knew before thanks.

Pinning is bad idea, then what is the use of Desktop? Also try to pin 100 shorcuts and tell me what you feel ;) I have very few thing pinned indeed to start them very very quickly.

Good call, forgot about Win-M.  Note though that Win-Shift-M is also used by the Screen Ruler Powertoy, so if you have that installed it'll conflict unless you change the mapping.

WIN+SHIFT-M does not restore minimized windows on my end. I do indeed have powertoys installed.

I usually use WIN+D and once again to restore it. Although, that won't work anymore if you launch something off of the desktop.

Win-Shift-M works to restore the desktop after remapping the Screen Ruler Powertoy activation keys.  It does, however, seem to not guarantee window focus when restoring.  I also have issues with it restoring apps to span across all 3 of my monitors (using a DisplayLink dock).

I've tested it a bit more and.. no, WIN+SHIT+M is not a solution. First of all WIN+M doesn't minimize non-minimizable windows, means it may not show desktop. Secondly, WIN+SHIFT+M has some problem to restore the state, e.g. snapped to sides windows, even if there were no changes done (no new window opened) after WIN+M...  As I said, press WIN+D twice, that's what I want (but with ability to double click something when desktop is shown), it work every time by simply showing desktop, WIN+M is something different, it tries to minimize windows.

After WIN+SHIFT+M I faced the bug with Chrome, where its window become topmost! Don't press WIN+SHIFT+M, it's hidden untested and buggy Microsoft feature.. ><

Works for me, possibly because I have switched off snapped windows and I don't have any "always on top with no minimize button" windows.
